# MongoDb Document Size Limit is 16MB, handle the situation if limit reaches

Tags: php, mongodb, document, bson

I am new to mongodb and i got to know about the size limit of 16mb for each document..
however my concerns are that my document would reach the size limit,
i have read everywhere people discussing about the limit 
but i dint find out any solution or workaroud to handle the limit reaching situation

my document schema is that i have one document and i am pusing new posts in it
there can be a million users posting on the same doucment... i cant change the schema if its not good ..
i dont know if this way i will ever reach the limit sooner or later
but is there any way to handle this situation 
is there some way we can switch collection if limit reaches 
am i being too concered about this limit size or is it fine to go with it considering my following schema

```
{
        "_id":"Object('someid')",
        Posts:[
   {
          post_id:"",
          post_user:"",
          post_user_eamil:"",
          posted_Data:"",
          image_url:"",
          comments:[
                     comment_id:"",
                     comment_user:"",
                     comment_user_eamil:"",
                     comment_Data:"",
                   ],

        ]
    }
}
```

Thanks alot and also correct me if i am wrong somewhere

Comment: There is a mechanism in mongodb called gridFS. Which basically divides a given file to chunks each on its own document

Comment: [*"Premature Optimization is the root of all evil"*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization). Welcome to StackOverflow, a site which incidently with it's own question and answer structure along with comments and votes, would be hard pressed ( would be interesting to see an actual percentage, but likely less than 0.00001% ) to have data in that structure exceed 16MB anywhere. And even so the only cases would be the most extreme response questions and with great age. Dealing with different data volumes when you have to is another broad issue. But don't believe the hype and don't overthink

Comment: You've introduced an unbounded-array condition into your documents: Since your `comments` array can grow without restriction, there's the possibility of exceeding maximum document size (regardless of the probability of it occurring, the possibility still exists). Nobody but you can answer the question regarding whether you'll hit the limit. Assuming you will hit it, you'll have no choice but to refactor how you store your comments (and how you do that is a matter of opinion).